# Merge multiple mux

Tags: verilog, circuit

For example, I have 8 independent 8-to-1 mux. They have the same input sources but different select signals.

out0 = input[sel0]
out1 = input[sel1]
...
out7 = input[sel7]

Is there a circuit implementing the above logic but using less gates than 8 independent 8-to-1 mux (8 * 7 2-to-1 mux)?

Comment: It will depend on the relation between selectors. If there's some dependency, it just might be possible to simplify the final design. But if selectors aren't related at all, then I don't think you can get any smaller than multiple independent muxes.

Comment: Let your synthesiser worry about that sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks @Vlad , I thought "same input sources" might bring some resource sharing.

Comment: MatthewTaylor's answer is pretty much spot on. Complex verilog statements to attempt to reduce logic, will usually just add logic or make it harder to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all independent variables, and taking the question at its face value. i.e., can we do better than *independent* MUXes, I would say YES since the decoding logic in the MUXes can be shared.